# windows 10 disk all of a sudden has no data and having I/O errors

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, device-manager

A drive i have been using for several years all of a sudden is not showing to have any data

trying to click the drive shows error

```
D:\ is not accessible.

The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
```

Please see screenshot below

[image]
[image]

What do i do here to be able to recover my data on the D:\ drive back again?
Thanks

Comment: One day or later, every disk will fail. That's why we have backups. Sometimes, the disk is still partially readable and you can recover some data. But this is really difficult because all you can access - if you can - are raw sectors on disk and you have to reconstitute the files which are made from a lot of sectors scattered all over the disk. If you have done a full defragmentation recently, then all untouched files are in a contiguous block of sector (Thats what defragmentation is) and it is easier to recover files.

Comment: am not sure what you saying here. Are you saying this means the disk has failed and nothing to do to recover files?

Comment: Since D: is BitLocker encrypted, there is little chance of recovering any data. Restore from your last disk image, instead, **if** the disk is still good.

Comment: bitlocker encrypted but it is decrypted as shown in the screenshot, so you saying no way to recover the data? what if i use a data recovery software like https://recoverit.wondershare.com/data-recovery-win.html

Comment: Recovery tools will work nicely if the damaged area is not on the file allocation table. If the table is damaged, then the recovery tool will have a bunch of readable sectors but no way to assemble it in files. The lesson: learn how to make backup before your next crash. Also learn what a RAID is and consider having one in your system.

Comment: First you should find out more about the error. Usually a disk does not fail from one second to the next. (1) See the Windows System Log for error entries of the type "disk" and check the error codes and their changes. Search for their explanation. (2) Check the S.M.A.R.T. information. There are several possibilities. One tool for this is [smartmontools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/files/). // Note that unnecessary physical usage can make things worse. So think about using your system without the power plug connected to the defective disk, when not analyzing this disk.